Spring Camel integration tests slow with Timeout message
After switching from RabbitMQ to Spring RabbitMQ, the maven failsafe tests have become slower, with multiple messages of

o.a.c.i.engine.DefaultShutdownStrategy   : Timeout occurred during graceful shutdown. Forcing the routes to be shutdown now. Notice: some resources may still be running as graceful shutdown did not complete successfully.

How to make the tests fast again?

This message is created by the DefaultShutdownStrategy. You can implement your own, like so:
public class QuickShutdown implements ShutdownStrategy
{
   @Override
   public void shutdownForced(final CamelContext context, final List<RouteStartupOrder> routes) throws Exception
   {
      routes.forEach(this::stopRoute);
   }

   private void stopRoute(RouteStartupOrder route) {
      route.getServices().forEach(Service::stop);
   }

   @Override
   public void shutdown(final CamelContext context, final List<RouteStartupOrder> routes) throws Exception
   {
      shutdownForced(context, routes);
   }

   @Override
   public void shutdown(final CamelContext context, final List<RouteStartupOrder> routes, final long timeout,
         final TimeUnit timeUnit)
         throws Exception
   {
      shutdownForced(context, routes);
   }

   @Override
   public boolean shutdown(final CamelContext context, final RouteStartupOrder route, final long timeout,
         final TimeUnit timeUnit,
         final boolean abortAfterTimeout) throws Exception
   {
      stopRoute(route);
      return false;
   }
// leave remainder of auto-generated methods empty
}

And use it in each integration test:
@Autowired
private CamelContext camelContext;
// ...
@Before
public void setup() {
    camelContext.setShutdownStrategy(new QuickShutdown());
}

or set this in a test configuration like so:
   @Bean
   CamelContextConfiguration contextConfiguration()
   {
      return new CamelContextConfiguration()
      {
         @Override
         public void beforeApplicationStart(@NonNull final CamelContext context)
         {
            context.setShutdownStrategy(new QuickShutdown());
         }
       // remaining method
    }}

(a more elegant solution is appreciated)

You should add this in your description not as a solution, since you are still looking for a solution.
